# Id generator in jpa (eclipselink) inheritance return random values

Tags: java, entity-framework, jpa, inheritance, eclipselink

I'm using eclipselink in my web application (i use vaadin with oracle as DATABASE) but i'm facing a problem with the Id values.

I have this simple schema :

```
   encaiss (@MappedSuperclass contains just Id)
                             |
                             |
       Encaissement (it extends encaiss so as to have the ID)
                 /                                   \
                /                                     \
Encaissement_Technique (extends Encaissement)          Encaissement_espece
       /                \
      /                  \
Encaissement_Cheque      Encaissement_Virement (both extend Encaissement_Technique to have the ID)
```

When i create an instance of Encaissement_virement for example, the Id generated is random eventhough i set **allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1**.

Those are the entities :

**====================Entity encaiss (contains just the ID)==============**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class encaiss {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="encaiss_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="encaiss_seq_gen", sequenceName="ENCAISSEMENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    protected long id_encaissement;

    public long getId_encaissement() {
        return id_encaissement;
    }

    public void setId_encaissement(long id_encaissement) {
        this.id_encaissement = id_encaissement;
    }

}
```

**============================entity Encaissement=======================**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ENCAISS_TYPE")
@Table(name="ENCAISSEMENT")
public class Encaissement extends encaiss implements Serializable{  

@Column(name="LIBELLE")
    protected String libelle;
    @Column(name="PIECE_JOINTE")
    protected String piece_jointe;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATE_ENCAISSEMENT")
    protected Date date_encaissement;
    @Embedded
    protected Avis_Recette avis_recette;

    public Encaissement(String libelle, String piece_jointe, Date date_encaissement){
        this.libelle=libelle;
        this.piece_jointe=piece_jointe;
        this.date_encaissement=date_encaissement;
    }

    public Encaissement(){

    }

}
```

**====================entity Encaissement_Technique======================**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Technique")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="ENCAISS_TECHNIQUE_TYPE")
@Table(name="ENCAISSEMENT_TECHNIQUE")
public class Encaissement_Technique extends Encaissement implements Serializable{

public Encaissement_Technique(){

    }

}
```

**====================entity Encaissement_Cheque========================**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
@Table(name="ENCAISSEMENT_CHEQUE")
public class Encaissement_Cheque extends Encaissement_Technique{

@Column(name="ETAT_AVISCREDIT")
    private String etat_avisCredit;
    @Embedded
    private Cheque cheque;

    public Encaissement_Cheque(String etat_avisCredit, Date date_encaissement){
        this.etat_avisCredit=etat_avisCredit;
        this.date_encaissement=date_encaissement;
    }

    public Encaissement_Cheque(){

    }

}
```

**====================entity Encaissement_Virement=======================**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("V")
@Table(name="ENCAISSEMENT_VIREMENT")
public class Encaissement_Virement extends Encaissement_Technique{

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="DATE_VIREMENT")
    private Date date_virement;

    public Encaissement_Virement(Date date_virement, String libelle, String piece_jointe, Float primCoass, Date date_encaissement){
        this.date_virement=date_virement;
        this.primeCoass=primCoass;
        this.piece_jointe=piece_jointe;
        this.libelle=libelle;
        this.date_encaissement=date_encaissement;
    }

    public Encaissement_Virement(){

    }

}
```

I created from eclipse an instance of Encaissement_virement, the generated id is 71 then when i create another it gives it 75, after that it jumps to 91 !!! then it's adding 3 after each insertion (i mean id=103 then 106 then 109) !!!!!

PS : When i excute

```
Encaissement_virement ev=new Encaissement_virement();
//ev.getters and setters
```

**ev.getId_Encaissement();** doesn't return the real Id instead **it returns 0** whether it is called before or after the commit.

This problem is driving me crazy and i can't figure out the problem. (i think that the inheritance id or the id type (which is long) are not working).

I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

***Edit :***

After using sql developer i'm convinced that the problem is in the inheritance.

This is what i get when i try to insert an Encaissement_virement (which is logical because it extends another entity) :

[image]

Can anyone help me fix the inheritance problem in jpa eclipselikn. Thanks again.

**Edit2**

I create a new instance of Encaissement_virement using this code :

```
JPAContainer<Encaissement_Espece> ee=JPAContainerFactory.make(Encaissement_Espece.class, PERSISTANCE_UNIT);
Encaissement_Espece encaissEspece;

JPAContainer<Encaissement_Cheque> ec=JPAContainerFactory.make(Encaissement_Cheque.class, PERSISTANCE_UNIT);
Encaissement_Cheque encaissCheque;

JPAContainer<Encaissement_Virement> ev=JPAContainerFactory.make(Encaissement_Virement.class, PERSISTANCE_UNIT);
Encaissement_Virement encaissVirement;
//Some code here.

                switch (typeEncaissement) {
            case 0:
                encaissEspece=new Encaissement_Espece();
                encaissEspece.setCaisse(caisseEnc);
                encaissEspece.setDate_encaissement(dateEnc);
                encaissEspece.setLibelle(libelleEnc);
                encaissEspece.setMontant(montantEncEspece);
                encaissEspece.setPiece_jointe(pieceJointesEnc);
                encaissEspece.setClient(clientEnc);

                //UUID uuid = (UUID)ee.addEntity(encaissEspece);
                //EntityItem<Encaissement_Espece> eeEntityItem = ee.getItem(uuid);

                IdEnc=(Long)ee.addEntity(encaissEspece);
                ee.commit();
                break;
            case 1:
                encaissCheque=new Encaissement_Cheque();
                encaissCheque.setBanque(banqueEnc);
                encaissCheque.setCheque(chequeEnc);
                encaissCheque.setClient(clientEnc);
                encaissCheque.setDate_encaissement(dateEnc);
                encaissCheque.setLibelle(libelleEnc);
                encaissCheque.setPiece_jointe(pieceJointesEnc);
                encaissCheque.setPrimeCoass(primeCoassEnc);

                IdEnc=(Long)ec.addEntity(encaissCheque);
                ec.commit();
                break;
            case 2:
                encaissVirement=new Encaissement_Virement();
                encaissVirement.setBanque(banqueEnc);
                encaissVirement.setClient(clientEnc);
                encaissVirement.setDate_encaissement(dateEnc);
                encaissVirement.setLibelle(libelleEnc);
                encaissVirement.setPiece_jointe(pieceJointesEnc);
                encaissVirement.setPrimeCoass(primeCoassEnc);
                encaissVirement.setDate_virement(dateVir);

                IdEnc=(Long)ev.addEntity(encaissVirement);
                ev.commit();
                break;

            default:
                break;
```

this is the result (a new anstance with 66 as id) : 
[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:25:45.301--ServerSession(5981709)--Connection(27335918)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-5,5,main])--SELECT ENCAISSEMENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:25:45.316--ClientSession(26722029)--Connection(27335918)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-5,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT** (ID_ENCAISSEMENT, DATE_ENCAISSEMENT, LIBELLE, PIECE_JOINTE, AGENCE, DATE_AVIS_RECETTE, ENDROIT, PROVENANCE, UNITE, ID_CLIENT, ENCAISS_TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [**66**, 2015-04-01, titre, jointes, null, null, null, null, null, 2, V]

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:25:45.795--ClientSession(26722029)--Connection(27335918)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-5,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT_TECHNIQUE** (PRIMECOASS, ID_BANQUE, ID_ENCAISSEMENT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [123.0, 1, **66**]

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:25:45.936--ClientSession(26722029)--Connection(27335918)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-5,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT_VIREMENT** (DATE_VIREMENT, ID_ENCAISSEMENT) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2015-04-01, **66**]
[image]

Then i drop this row and create another instance with the same code, and i get :

[image]

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:30:42.119--ServerSession(27444543)--Connection(6011948)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-15,5,main])--SELECT ENCAISSEMENT_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:30:42.13--ClientSession(1011455)--Connection(6011948)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-15,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT** (ID_ENCAISSEMENT, DATE_ENCAISSEMENT, LIBELLE, PIECE_JOINTE, AGENCE, DATE_AVIS_RECETTE, ENDROIT, PROVENANCE, UNITE, ID_CLIENT, ENCAISS_TYPE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [**69**, 2015-04-01, titre, j, null, null, null, null, null, 4, V]

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:30:42.195--ClientSession(1011455)--Connection(6011948)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-15,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT_TECHNIQUE** (PRIMECOASS, ID_BANQUE, ID_ENCAISSEMENT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    bind => [123.0, 1, **69**]

[EL Fine]: sql: 2015-04-01 17:30:42.211--ClientSession(1011455)--Connection(6011948)--Thread(Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-15,5,main])--**INSERT INTO ENCAISSEMENT_VIREMENT** (DATE_VIREMENT, ID_ENCAISSEMENT) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2015-04-01, **69**]

You can notice that instead of getting 67 as Id i get 69 ??

Comment: you are using a sequence for the generation why don't you specify GenerationType.SEQUENCE instead of GenerationType.AUTO ?

Comment: It was a mistake as i have many entities (copy paste ) :p but this doesn't solve the problem. It's like when i create an Encaissement_virement it allocate 3 ids (one for Encaissement, one for Encaissement_technique and one for Encaissement_virement, although they have all the same id). 

In ddl it works fine, the id is incremented by 1 but with jpa it doesn't work (always a gap of 3 ) !!!!!

Comment: I think you need to check if your model is correct.
- Is it possible to have an instance of Encaissement ?
- Why do you need Encaissement and encaiss ? could you merge them ?

Comment: encaiss is not an entity it is just a @MappedSuperclass that gather the common parameters (such as ID or version number). So encaiss will not generate a table in the database. And yes i can get an instance of Encaissement, the only problem is that the id is always incremeted by 3 (and not 1).

Thanks for your reply mate.

Comment: Why do you have inheritance defined on Encaissement_Technique?  It should only have Entity,  DiscriminatorValue and Table annotations, as everything else it should get from its parent.  As for the ID returning 0 - you should start with a simple model and then expand on it.  This issue is likely that you are checking an unmanaged instance.  Since it is unmanaged, JPA is unaware of it and will never set its pk with a value.  As for the id incrementing  by 3.. can you show a simple code example demonstrating your issue?  you might try turning on Eclipselink logging to finest to see the statements

Comment: The inheritance in Encaissement_Technique is because this entity have two children (Encaissement_Cheque and Encaissement_Virement). For the id returning 0 i've fixed it (now i use the addEntity which return the exact Id). As for the incrementation, i've edited2 the question.

Thanks.